# Julia ReadOnlyMemoryError with ODBC SQL query

Tags: sql, function, odbc, julia

I'm working on writing a function that queries a SQL database and I'm encountering a ReadOnlyMemoryError() that has me stumped. The issue is that when I run my code as a simple script everything functions as expected. But when I try to wrap the exact same code in a function I get the ReadOnlyMemoryError().

Here's the script version of my code:

```
using ODBC
using DBInterface
using Dates
using DataFrames

server = "server string "
username = "username "
password = " password"
db = " db name"

start_date=Nothing
end_date=Nothing

if start_date == Nothing || typeof(start_date) != "Date"
    start_date = Dates.today() - Dates.Day(30)
end

if end_date == Nothing || typeof(end_date) != "Date"
    end_date = Dates.today()
end

query = """ SQL SELECT statement """

connect_string = "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=" * server *
                ";DATABASE=" * db *
                ";UID=" * username *
                ";PWD=" * password
conn = ODBC.Connection(connect_string)

df = DBInterface.execute(conn, query) |> DataFrame
```

This works as expected, the result is a dataframe df with about 500k rows. However, when I try use this same code to make a reusable function I get the error:

```
using ODBC
using DBInterface
using Dates
using DataFrames

function get_cf_data(start_date=Nothing, end_date=Nothing)
    server = " server string "
    username = " user name"
    password = " password"
    db = " db "

    if start_date == Nothing || typeof(start_date) != "Date"
        start_date = Dates.today() - Dates.Day(30)
    end

    if end_date == Nothing || typeof(end_date) != "Date"
        end_date = Dates.today()
    end

    query = """  SQL SELECT statement """

    connect_string = "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=" * server *
                    ";DATABASE=" * db *
                    ";UID=" * username *
                    ";PWD=" * password
    conn = ODBC.Connection(connect_string)

    df = DBInterface.execute(conn, query) |> DataFrame

    return df
end
```

In this case, when I try to call from REPL get_cf_data() I get ERROR: ReadOnlyMemoryError(). I'm somewhat new to Julia, so any insight would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Please show how you are calling the function. Is it in a loop? Also, be sure to close ODBC connection after query call. Finally, I hope you are [parameterizing date values](https://juliadatabases.github.io/ODBC.jl/latest/#Query-execution-and-result-handling-1) and not concatenating to SQL. No `params` arg is used in `execute`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! It looks like closing the ODBC connection was the issue, I added that line and now it's working as expected. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As commented, best practice in most programming languages when integrating APIs like ODBC connections is to close and release its resource after usage.

Additionally, consider [parameterization](https://juliadatabases.github.io/ODBC.jl/latest/#Query-execution-and-result-handling-1) (best practice in any language running SQL that passes literal values) where you set up a prepared SQL statement and bind values in a subsequent `execute` call.

```
function get_cf_data(start_date=Nothing, end_date=Nothing)
    server = " server string "
    username = " user name"
    password = " password"
    db = " db "

    if isnothing(start_date) || typeof(start_date) != "Date"
        start_date = Dates.today() - Dates.Day(30)
    end

    if isnothing(end_date) || typeof(end_date) != "Date"
        end_date = Dates.today()
    end

    # PREPARED STATEMENT WITH QMARK PLACEHOLDERS
    sql = """SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, ...
             FROM myTable
             WHERE myDate BETWEEN ? AND ?
          """

    connect_string = "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=" * server *
                    ";DATABASE=" * db *
                    ";UID=" * username *
                    ";PWD=" * password
    conn = ODBC.Connection(connect_string)

    # PREPARE STATEMENT AND BIND PARAMS
    stmt = DBInterface.prepare(conn, sql)
    df = DBInterface.execute(stmt, (start_date, end_date)) |> DataFrame

    DBInterface.close(stmt)                   # CLOSE STATEMENT
    DBInterface.close(conn)                   # CLOSE CONNECTION
    stmt = Nothing; conn = Nothing            # UNINTIALIZE OBJECTS

    return df
end
```